# Get email notifications when new version of a package published

Tags: node.js, npm

There used to be some projects available for achieving this rather useful task ([one](http://outof.me/stay-up-to-date-with-node-js-packages-using-npm-onupdate-service/), [two](http://npmalerts.com/)), but they seem to be shut down.

I came across the [NPM hooks](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/145260155635/introducing-hooks-get-notifications-of-npm), but it doesn't give an out-of-the-box way to have human readable notifications (emails or something along those lines).

Since an average NodeJS app depends on a *number* of 3rd party packages and new versions of those are published with a striking pace, I'm a little bit surprised that this feature isn't built in [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com) website in the first place.

I don't find doing `npm outdated` and so on terribly handy on a regular basis. Nobody wants routinely check for updates in case he just might get a notification when it happens.

So, how can we get email notifications when new version of a package published to NPM?

Comment: check out https://npmnotifier.party/

Comment: @avrahamcool: Thank you! Will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/145260155635/introducing-hooks-get-notifications-of-npm

That may help you to get started...

Comment: Thank you, I've come across those hooks, but it seems you need to implement some stuff in code to make it work as a email notifications service.

Answer (score 4):

If the package is on GitHub as most are you can also use RSS feed notifcations:

`https://github.com/THE_PACKAGE_REPO/releases.atom`

Then use the many available methods to get notified. I download a free simple app from MacOS App Store that checks at interals.

Comment: This works well with a service like Zapier (including the free plan), which can notify when an RSS feed has new items.

Comment: Indeed. I also just came across https://newreleases.io/

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not ideal, but one trick I've used is to put this:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/PACKAGE-NAME/v/2.0.0
```

as the URL in an uptime monitoring service and set it to notify you based on the existence of a keyword string (uptime robot has this on their free plan) that will definitely occur in the README. This only works if you're waiting to be notified for a *specific* version number that you know will be published at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need, and opted for this (very generic) service: https://visualping.io/

the free version is more than enough